# Polarization of light confusion

Tags: optics, waves

I started learning about polarization and came to learn an unpolarized light is one in which electric field symmetrically in all direction.Does this mean in a single light wave we have electric field vibrations in all direction or that an unpolarized light is a mixture of many polarized light in different directions?

Comment: The latter. Unpolarised light (also often called randomly polarised light) is light where there is no single axis that the E-fields of all components oscillate along. The individual axes of oscillation are randomly distributed to form the overall unpolarised/randomly polarised beam.

Comment: @Holzner That looks more like an answer than a comment...

Comment: Perpendicular to the propagation direction that is.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yeah I thought that but then it didn't have any pretty pictures and isn't really as comprehensive as I would want it to be for a good answer. Will check the guidelines again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unpolarized light consists of light of all polarizations, thus the signal doesn't exhibit a dominance in *one* polarization. Your second guess is the correct one.